# Display answer once

Tags: java, max

So my assignment for programming is to make a program that reads ten user inputs and then informs the user which one is of the highest value. As shown below, it does that perfectly and I got 100% on the assignment.

However, I want to polish the coding structure so that every time when the user enters a bigger value after being prompted to do so, (such as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) the output would not be displayed 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9; with 9 being the final output.

How can I get rid of all the values preceding 9 so that the output would just be 9?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Army{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // declares an array of doubles
        double[] inputArray = new double[10];
        // allocates memory for 10 doubles
        System.out.println("Please enter ten numbers.");
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length ; j++) {
                inputArray[(int) j] = in.nextDouble();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        double maxValue = inputArray[0];
        for (int i=0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i] > maxValue){ 
                maxValue = inputArray[i];
                System.out.println("The largest number is "+maxValue+".");
            }else{
                System.out.println("The largest number is "+inputArray[i]+".");
                // optional: display only one answer.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your code as follows.

```
double maxValue = inputArray[0];
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
   if (inputArray[i] > maxValue) {
        maxValue = inputArray[i];
         // removed print from here
        } else {
         // removed print from here too
        }
  }
System.out.println("max value is: "+maxValue); //print max from out side the loop
```